# How can I discretize the numeric variables without losing the original ones?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

Here is my toy data with code. How can I discretize the numeric variables without losing the original ones?

```
library(gapminder); library(tidyverse); library(tidymodels)

gapminder %>% 
  recipe(lifeExp ~ .) %>% 
  step_discretize(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), options = list(cuts = 10)) %>% 
  prep() %>% 
  juice()
```

In the above code I loose the original values from the pop and gdpPercap as they are replaced with their respective discretized verions. How can I keep both: original numeric values as well as discretised variables?

Secondly, instead of bin01, bin02, isn't there a way to get the [0-100], [101-150], etc. kind of bins so I know which bin has what values?

Comment: This recipe step does not have a `preserve` argument in the way that `step_dummy()` does. If you would like to [open an issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues) explaining why you want to keep both the original and discretized version in your modeling workflow, we can look at it and prioritize this idea for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do this using step_discretize with left_joining the data again, but there is a discretize function from arules package that renders bins with values. Here is the what worked for me.

```
gapminder %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric),  
      ~arules::discretize(x = .x, method = "interval", breaks = 10), 
         .names = "bin_{col}"))
```

In case, you know how to do this within recipe, do let me know.

Comment: Arules's discretize function is the best according to me. Someone let us know how to incorporate this in recipes.